# How to open a confirm dialog on check of p:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` that shows a dialog to confirm an action :

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isModel" value="#{managedBean.isModel}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="PF('confirmDialog').show()" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

On change of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` the `confirmDialog` shows up :

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" widgetVar="confirmDialog" closable="false" width="50%" >        
    <p:commandButton value="oui" ..... />
    <p:commandButton value = "non" ...../> 
</p:confirmDialog>
```

How can i use `javascript` to  open this dialog only when i check `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`, and when i uncheck it triggers another action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check the value before showing the dialog:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isModel" value="#{managedBean.isModel}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" oncomplete="if(#{not managedBean.isModel}) PF('confirmDialog').show()" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

What should the other action be? You could also use a listener and open the dialog with it:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isModel" value="#{managedBean.isModel}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{managedBean.isModel}/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Bean:

```
public void isModel() {
if(isModel) {    
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('confirmDialog').show();");
    }
else{
    // do some other action
    }
}
```

Comment: checking the value that way does not work, it shows an error

Comment: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /pages/eqpt.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 155] Le type d'élément "p:selectBooleanCheckbox" doit être suivi des spécifications d'attribut, ">" ou "/>"

Comment: sorry my log is not in english

Comment: I've tested the first method, for me it works. You just have to add a not to the if, because the oncomplete is performed before the value has changed. I've updated my answer. The error must be somewhere else in your code or a copy / paste mistake.

Comment: i've tried if(#{not managedBean.isModel}) PF('confirmDialog').show(), the dialog shows up in both cases

Comment: because you didn't process the value to the bean, so it is always false and the condition is always right so the dialog shows up, just add process="@this" to the p:ajax tag.

Comment: the value im using is from an entity, i don't think this is the problem

Comment: it worked fine, i had to add an update of selectBooleanCheckbox in ajax